# How to send SMS using Twilio after 48 hours in NextJs?

Tags: next.js, twilio

I am working on a NextJs project and want to use Twilio to send some SMS to users. I want to send SMS to users according to some condition, for example, if they have not completed registration.Therefore, I am not familiar with Twilio and don't have any idea how to do that. Please instruct me on how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

- You use a **messaging service to send a scheduled SMS** at a predefined  time. This approach requires you to define when the message needs to be sent in advance, and you would need to [cancel it](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#cancel-a-scheduled-message) if the user completes the registration.

  ```js
  const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

  client.messages
      .create({
         messagingServiceSid: 'MGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
         body: 'This is a scheduled message',
         sendAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 10, 30, 20, 36, 27)),
         scheduleType: 'fixed',
         to: '+15558675310'
       })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
  ```

- You run a batch job every day and check if there are incomplete registration from the two previous days and send the message out to the relevant users. This could also be done without a messaging service.

  ```js
  const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

  client.messages
      .create({
         messagingServiceSid: 'MGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
         body: 'This is a regular message',
         to: '+15558675310'
       })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
  ```